# How to delete a certain value in a cell in columns of csv using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

I need help with deleting "None" along with extra comma in `language` columns that have one or more language

Here is the existing csv:

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'Movie': ['name1','name2','name3','name4'],
                  'Year': ['1905', '1905','1906','1907'],
                  'Id': ['tt0283985', 'tt0283986','tt0284043','tt3402904'],
                  'language':['Mandarin,None','None,Cantonese','Mandarin,None,Cantonese','None,Cantonese']})
```

Where `f` now looks like:

```
   Movie  Year         Id   language
0  name1  1905  tt0283985  Mandarin,None
1  name2  1905  tt0283986  None,Cantonese
2  name3  1906  tt0284043  Mandarin,None,Cantonese
3  name4  1907  tt3402904  None,Cantonese
```

And the result should be like this:

```
   Movie  Year         Id             language
0  name1  1905  tt0283985            Mandarian
1  name2  1905  tt0283986            Cantonese
2  name3  1906  tt0284043            Mandarin,Cantonese
3  name4  1907  tt3402904            Cantonese
```

There are also other columns that have only 'None' values in language column, so I can't just use the replace function in excel, and there's also a problem of extra "," after doing that. So I may need help with a new way using pandas or something.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve it this way,

```
f["language"] = f.apply(
    lambda x: ",".join(filter(lambda y: y != "None", x.language.split(","))), axis=1
)
```

Or much better

```
f["language"] = f.apply(
    lambda x: ",".join([y for y in x.language.split(",") if y != "None"]), axis=1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just remove all the None values as follows:

```
df['language'] = df['language'].str.replace('None,', '')
```

and then wherever the language column is empty, you could insert a 'None' value using regex.

```
df['language'] = df['language'].replace(r'^\s*$', 'None', regex=True)
```

Comment: That helps, and I add: df['language'] = df['language'].str.replace('None,', '') so it replace all None. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace method to remove 'None' and ','

```
for i in range(len(f)):
f.loc[i,"language"].replace('None','')
f.loc[i,"language"].replace(',','')
print(f)
```